How can we compute the Expectation of Log of Truncated Gamma over (0, 1]?
How can we compute $\mathbb{E} \left[ \log \text{Gamma}_{(0, 1]} (\alpha, \beta) \right]$?
Right now I'm using a Monte Carlo estimator by sampling from the Truncated Gamma distribution over $(0, 1]$ (using the method presented here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534318/how-to-sample-from-truncated-distributions-using-scipy) and computing the mean of the log of the samples.
Is there a closed form for $\mathbb{E} \left[ \log \text{Gamma}_{(0, 1]} (\alpha, \beta) \right]$? If not, is there a better way to do this?
